# Executing stored procedures in oracle inside a package using dbms_job

Tags: oracle, dbms-job

I am trying to execute multiple stored procedures through package using DBMS_JOB. Even if the job is getting submitted and is showing in USER_JOBS its not getting started for some reason. I have tried with and without putting the 'START DATE' parameter with the same result i.e. no start.

I am using ORACLE 9i and i guess i cannot use dbms_scheduler.

Find below the code :

```
--PACKAGE BODY--

create or replace
PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST IS

  PROCEDURE PASSPORT_DC_1 IS

  l_jobno binary_integer;
  l_jobno1 binary_integer;

    BEGIN

       dbms_job.submit(l_jobno1, 'BEGIN SP_ABC(); END;',SYSDATE );
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SP_UPDATE_TIDCUMTL :' || l_jobno1);
       COMMIT;

       dbms_job.submit(l_jobno, 'BEGIN SP_XYZ(); END;',SYSDATE);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SP_UPDATE_TIDPTDTL :' || l_jobno);
       COMMIT; 

  END PASSPORT_DC_1;

--PACKAGE SPEC--

create or replace PACKAGE PKG_TEST AS

  PROCEDURE PASSPORT_DC_1;

END PKG_TEST;
```

Comment: Its a while since I used 9i but try setting start_date to SYSDATE + 1/1440. Check that the job definition is as you expect by looking in DBA_JOBS and that the job isn't 'broken'. Then see if you can force the job to run using DBMS_JOB.RUN with the jobid.

Comment: when i try to run it manually by doing DBMS_JOB.RUN(job id). It is executing, but the purpose of parallelism is defeated as DBMS_JOB.RUN(job id) executes the jobs sequentially. in the example there are 2 jobs which must start in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

the 3. parameter of the dbms_job.submit is the interval [(see doc)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#i1001473). try to omit the third parameter (SYSDATE) if you whant to run you stored procedure only once.:

```
dbms_job.submit(l_jobno1, 'BEGIN SP_ABC(); END;');
```

Comment: I have run omitting the last parameter as well. 

    dbms_job.submit(l_jobno1, 'BEGIN SP_ABC(); END;' );
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SP_ABC() :' || l_jobno1);
           COMMIT;

still the job is not starting